# How to use the current date as an argument?

Tags: batch-file, csv, sql, sql-server-2008, date

I have a batch script which extract SQL data to CSV file:

`bcp Database.dbo.MyTable out C:\Reports\Output.csv -s ServerName -T -c`

I need the name of the output file to contain the current date.

For example the output file has to be of the following format: `Result_2012_12_31csv`.

I guess the DATE function has to be used here as an argument.

How I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want (as I understand it).

```
bcp Database.dbo.MyTable out C:\Reports\Output_%date:~10,4%_%date:~4,2%_%date:~7,2%.csv -s ServerName -T -c
```

would result in:

```
bcp Database.dbo.MyTable out C:\Reports\Output_2012_08_14.csv -s ServerName -T -c
```

Comment: The further question is how to transfer headings as well? The output file does not contain them.